# QSQLDatabase open and close on each transaction?

Tags: mysql, qt

I have single connection to a database for use in a inventory application that I'm developing.

What I'm doing right now is calling open() everytime I need to do a query to the dB and then doing close().

Is there any benefit to doing this, rather than just opening the connection and leaving it open?

Comment: Opening a database connection can be expensive, you don't want to do it everytime you run a query.

Answer (score 0):

open database like this:

```
QSqlError MainWindow::addConnection(QString host,QString dbName,QString user,QString pw)
{
    QSqlError err;
    QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName(host);
    db.setDatabaseName(dbName);
    db.setUserName(user);
    db.setPassword(pw);
    if (!db.open())
    {
        qDebug()<<u8"err";
        err=db.lastError();
        QSqlDatabase db1=QSqlDatabase::database();
        QString name = db1.connectionName();
        QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(name);
    }
    return err;
}
```

and in the main.app:

```
void addConnections(manage *w)
{
    QSqlError err=w->addConnection("","","","");
    if (err.type()!=QSqlError::NoError)
    {
        qDebug() << "Unable to open connection:" << err;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    addConnections(&w);
    return a.exec();
}
```

It can be opening at the begining. And everytime you want to use it, just do like:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.exec("SELECT * FROM data");
```

If you have several links, you can just add name after the initialization and call it with the name.

Comment: Yeah I do this. I just wanted to know if I need to open it every time. That´s all. Thanks!